# Quotes not rendering properly in WooCommerce settings API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, settings-api

hello i'm using a setting API of woocommerce for creating form fields.
what i want here is to fetch emails from database and display it in a dropdown in frontend
now have fetch the emails but when i assing that to the options field all quotes are converted to '"'

using class WC_Payment_Gateway

refered [this](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/settings-api/) to write form fields code

code that i'm using for fetching emails is

```
 $blogusers = get_users();
            // Array of stdClass objects.
            $str = "";
             foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
            $str .= '"'.$user->user_email.'" =\> __("'.$user->user_email.'", "mails"),';
            }           
            $str = rtrim($str,',');
```

this is how i'm using it to create dropdown

```
$this->form_fields = array('sec_r2_mail' => array(
                    'title' => __('Receiver 2 Mail', 'mail'),
                    'type' => 'select',
                  'label' => __('Emails', 'mail'),
                    'default' => '', 
                  'options' => array($str)));
```

what i expect is:

```
"demo1@gmail.com" => __("demo1@gmail.com", "mails"),"demo2@gmail.com" => __("demo2@gmail.com", "mails")
```

what i get when i do view page source is:

```
&quot;demo1@gmail.com&quot; =&gt; __(&quot;demo1@gmail.com&quot;, &quot;mails&quot;), &quot;demo2@gmail.com&quot; =&gt; __(&quot;demo2@gmail.com&quot;, &quot;mails&quot;)
```

that is the reason dropdown is not rendered properly, where i'm going wrong or am i missing something here. what i should do so that " are not transformed to "
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a string representation of an array, when you need an actual array!

```
$blogusers = get_users();
$options = array();

foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    $options[ $user->user_email ] = $user->user_email; // No need to pass through __(), don't translate emails!
}
```

And then pass it to your `options` argument:

```
$this->form_fields = array(
    'sec_r2_mail' => array(
        'options' => $options,
        // Other arguments
    ),  
);
```

Comment: thank you @TheDeadMedic +1 for your answer this solved my query sorry giving +1 here as don't have that much reputation points